# Skip save of field collection attached to entity without removing reference to field collection?

Tags: 7, entities

I've got a node form encumbered with many field collections and node save takes forever.

I would like to "lock" some of those field collections and forgo saving them on node save. Kind of like skip_host_save but the opposite.

I've tried removing the field collection form elements but that deletes them from the node.

Here's the function I have which deletes the field collections from the node, called from hook_form_alter.

```
/**
 * @param $element FC to unset.
 *
 * Unset all the form api fields that would cause this field collection to be saved.
 */
function freshstop_usability_unset_fs(&$element) {
  foreach(element_children($element) as $index){
    unset($element[$index]);
  }
  unset($element['#entity_type']);
  unset($element['#bundle']);
  unset($element['#entity']);
  unset($element['#field_name']);
  unset($element['#columns']);
  unset($element['#element_validate']);
  $element['field_locked_markup'] = array(
    '#markup' => 'This field collection is older than one year and can no longer be edited.'
  );
}
```